# How to make the underlying views gray

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, grayscale

I have a UILabel and a UIButton on the UIView (as **ORIGIN** in screenshot), and then are there any technology to make they gray temporarily? (as **EXPECTED** in screenshot)

I've try to create a UIVIew (Background color #6666 and alpha 0.75) front of them and get **ACTUAL**.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5xhH.jpg "screenshot"

By the way, the **ACTUAL** screen shot is captured when presenting a UIAlertController.

Comment: are you setting the alpha value of view or background color?? It looks like you are settings view alpha value ...

Comment: You may be interested in https://github.com/freshking/BKFilterView

Comment: I would not change any color related properties of UIView elements under the GRAY UIView.

Comment: Can't you just set UIView color to expected grey color and similar for button tittle color

Comment: In real case, I would like to present another subclass of UIViewController (fooViewController) front of current view, and the fooViewController would only render little views (as UIAlertController).

Answer (score 1):

Don't set alpha 0.75 instead set 1.0 and you can set title colour for button either in storyboard or xib if you are using storyboard or nib file. You can also set title colour programatically.

[button setTitleColor:[UIColor lightTextColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

here button is your button reference and you can set any colour you want.

**Edited:**
If you have clicked actual image with alert view then you can also set with 0.75 alpha what is best suited you. What only diff i can see is the colour of button text. Which you can set from above mentions methods.

Comment: In real case, I would like to get the same effect as when presenting UIAlertController; gray behind view (means NOT AVAILABLE in case).

Comment: Then you have to add overlay on top of that.